# Splitting a String then iterating over that list

Tags: python

Basically what I'm supposed to do is make a program that gets the half-steps of a cord, and outputs the cord that many half steps away. I got that working, but I'm not sure what I need to do for my string_to_list function, where I am supposed to split the string that's getting passed into the function then iterate over that list that I split into create tuples.

If someone could help I'd really appreciate it.

```
def string_to_list(chords_str):
    return chords_str.split()
```

Comment: Why do you think you need such a function? And you are already splitting the list there; if you returned the result of `chords_str.split()` rather than throwing it away, wouldn't you get what you need?

Comment: Yes, that gives me exactly what I need, but I'm being asked to implement something like that into my string_to_list function.

Comment: If I return chords_str.split()
Enter the amount of half-steps: -1
D E7 A7 D Gbm G Gbm Em D
>>>

Comment: After you make the list (of strings), make a list of tuples. Each of the tuples will consist of two parts: the root of the chord and the variation of the chord. For example, "D" becomes ("D", ""), "Dsus2" becomes ("D", "sus2"), "F#" becomes ("F#", ""), "F#m" becomes ("F#", "m").

This is what I need to be done inside of my string_to_list.

Comment: What is the format of the tuple output your looking for from the string_to_list function?

Comment: So if it was for instance, "D" it would become ("D", "") "Fsus3" ("F", "sus3")

Comment: how do you identify the root vs variation, is the first char of the string always the root but in one of your comments you said 'F#m' 'F#' is the root and 'm' is the variation. What is the demarcation between root and variation?

Comment: "A Bb B C Db D Eb E F Gb G Ab"

"A A# B C C# D D# E F F# G G#"

These are the scales, therefore would be the roots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading you right I believe code like this will get you what your looking for:

```
chord_str = 'D D#m Fsus2 Bbmaj7'
test = chord_str.split(' ')
new_list_of_tuples = []
for chord in test:
  if '#' in chord or 'b' in chord:
    new_list_of_tuples.append((chord[:2], chord[2:]))
  else:
    new_list_of_tuples.append((chord[:1], chord[1:]))

print(new_list_of_tuples)

[('D', ''), ('D#', 'm'), ('F', 'sus2'), ('Bb', 'maj7')]
```

You check to see if a sharp or flat is in the chord name to adjust where you split the string and then add the rest of the string into a tuple.

Comment: This would be the string_to_list?

Comment: Yeah you would pass the `chord_str` to the `string_to_list` function then split the string into a list then check each element of the list for the root seperate the root from the variation store it in a tuple and append it to a new list and return that list to do whatever else you need to do in your script

Comment: You'll probably need to return the new list with the tuples from the function I wrote I didn't put a return statement

Comment: so just return new_list_of_tuples ?

Comment: Yes as far as I can tell from your error and the code.  I just wrote that as a working example to show that it works you'll need to properly format it as a function and return the list of tuples so you can pass that to your other functions in your script

Answer (score 0):

Hope this solves your issues:
In your transpose function i see that you are creating a scale which i believe is the list of roots.

So i pass the chors string and scale to the string_to_list function.
Then for each chord if it start with a root the split the chord on root gives you two items 1. root, 2. variation and hence you can form the tuple.

```
def string_to_list(chords_str, scale):
    tuple_list = []
    chord_list = chords_str.split()
    for chord in chord_list:
        for root in scale:
            if chord.startswith('root'):
                value = (root, chord.split(root)[1])
                tuple_list.append(value)
                break

    return tuple_list
```